# How to find distinct columns with django?

Tags: mysql, django

I have a model like this:

```
class Portfolio(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
        project = models.ForeignKey(ProjectDetail, null=True, blank=True)
        image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_path, max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
        caption = models.CharField(_('Caption'), max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
        added_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I want to find three portfolios ordered by added_on date with distinct user.

I.e.: Something like this

```
Portfolio.objects.all().order_by('-added_on').distinct('user')[:3]
```

I know this works in `postgresql` but not in `mysql`, is there any way to achieve the same end result using `mysql`?

Comment: It should be same for all of the DB's because django itself takes care of the drivers and makes translation wrt to DB engine that you specify in settings file

Comment: No its not:I get this error : NotImplementedError: DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend

Comment: According to this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#mysql-notes  , mysql should have no problem using `DISTINCT`. Using oracle/sqlite can have problem with distinct

Comment: @S.Ali Django's feature support is still limited by the capabilities of the specific backend. PostgreSQL supports `DISTINCT ON` queries, the other backends do not. Django implemented a function that translates to a `DISTINCT ON` query, but naturally it does not work with MySQL and other databases that do not support it.

Answer (score 1):

Actually `.distinct([*fields])` only works in `PostgresSQL`  Consult the [distinct](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct) documentation
You can use query somewhat related to this

```
Portfolio.objects.order_by('-added_on').values('user').distinct()
```

Consult [values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values) docs.
Hope that helps.

Comment: This way i will get values for user and not of portfolios.. i wish i could downvote this answer . :(

Answer (score 0):

This can be **an agnostic database approach**:

```py
from django.db.models import Max

#select the last 3 user touching Portfolio:
last3users = (User
              .objects
              .annotate(last_touch=Max('portfolio__added_on'))
              .order_by('-last_touch')
             )[:3]

#select last portfolio for each user
last3portfolios = [ Portfolio.objects.filter( user = u ).last('added_on') 
                    for u in last3users ]
```

As you can see **you get 4 database access instead of one** is the price to pay in this case to get this piece of code free of specific database features, it seems reasonable in this scenario. *disclaimer: not tested*

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.db.models import Max, F

(Portfolio.objects.order_by('added_on')
 .annotate(most_recent=Max('user__portfolio__added_on'))
 .filter(most_recent=F('added_on'))[:3])
```

Annotations can be filtered on. `most_recent=Max('user__portfolio__added_on')` will annotate each row with the latest `added_on` date for that portfolio's user. The `F` object allows you to filter based on the value of a database field.

Note that this will not handle the edge case where `added_on` has the same value for multiple entries. This can become a problem if you often create multiple objects using `bulk_create` (though I don't even know if that handles the `auto_add_now` option correctly).